# Can multiple closures to add variables to a function's scope be simplified?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to pass two variables to a `filereader` callback. Essentially I'm looping over files and displaying thumbnails of them; to accomplish this, I need two variables (in this case, `parent` and `canvas`). The code below works, but I want to be sure my future self won't hate my present self.

I assume that passing two variables into the scope of a callback function without overwriting `this` is a fairly common case.

This code is using a namespace (parent), which could be avoided, but I would still like to know how to pass two variables into a callback function.

```
reader.onload = (function (parent) { // even funkier closure to access the parent, the canvas, and the file
    return function(canvas) { // funky closure to be able access the canvas and file
        return function(r) {
            canvas.sourceImage.src = r.target.result;
            parent.functions.render(canvas);
            parent.functions.preview(canvas, canvas.sourceImage.width/10, canvas.sourceImage.height/10);
        };
    }(parent.canvases[j]);
})(parent);

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

---

Per comments, here's the full code. I'm not particularly looking for a code review (`there's a stack for that!`), but any feedback is appreciated.

```
(function () {
    this.readFiles = function (parent) {
        var files = parent.fileInput.files;
        var j = parent.canvases.length; // so we don't overwrite old previews
        for (var  i = 0; i < files.length; i++, j++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var reader = new FileReader;

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.id = "previewCanvas" + j;
            canvas.className = parent.canvasClasses;
            canvas.width = 100;
            canvas.height = 100;
            parent.previewWrapper.appendChild(canvas);

            /* Initialize Canvases for each file */
            parent.canvases[j] = this.create(document.getElementById('previewCanvas' + j));

            reader.onload = (function (parent) { // even funkier closure to access the parent, the canvas, and the file
                return function(canvas) { // funky closure to be able access the file
                    return function(r) {
                        canvas.sourceImage.src = r.target.result;
                        parent.functions.render(canvas);
                        parent.functions.preview(canvas, canvas.sourceImage.width/10, canvas.sourceImage.height/10);
                    };
                }(parent.canvases[j]);
            })(parent);

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
}).apply(Canvas.functions);
```

Comment: You could always pass a single object containing both variables

Comment: You can just do `var canvas = parent.canvases[j];` and it will be accessible in the inner function.

Comment: Why do you need the `function(canvas)` function at all? Wouldn't just assigning `var canvas = parent.canvases[j];` achieve the same goal? Also, just a note, future self *always* hates present self.

Comment: You could probably even just pass two arguments, `parent` and `canvas` to the outer function if you preferred.

Comment: You need to show more code or explain a few things to get a useful answer. It's not possible to make an informed suggestion with just this snippet. What is `parent`? Does it change? Does `canvas` change? If these do not change, there is no need for a closure on them. What is `j`? Presumably a loop index? Show the loop, because that is involved directly in how to best write this code.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - see edit. As mentioned in the question, `parent` is a namespace to make this modular. It's my first experiment with namespacing; I think the general question is valid even if the example can be solved in other ways.

Comment: @MattBurland - sounds like an answer. That does seem to work - I had forgotten that the outer function would be executed synchronously even though the inner would be executed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @MichaelGeary mostly answered my question by restructuring the code, the answer to the title question is that the outer function is executed immediately, and has access to the current variables:

```
reader.onload = (function (parent) { 

   var canvas = parent.canvases[j];
   // put more variables ad nauseum here. 
   // They will be passed to the return function without being changed.

   return function(r) {
        canvas.sourceImage.src = r.target.result;
        parent.functions.render(canvas);
        parent.functions.preview(canvas, [...]);
        };
})(parent);
```

This way you can use counters and other variables likely to change if needed inside of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can get rid most of the closures and a few other bits of code too.

This should work, barring any bugs I've introduced... And with the two bugs that you noted now fixed, thanks for catching them! :-)

```
function forEach( array, callback ) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( array, callback );
}

Canvas.functions.readFiles = function( parent ) {
    forEach( parent.fileInput.files, function( file ) {
        var reader = new FileReader;

        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        canvas.id = 'previewCanvas' + parent.canvases.length;
        canvas.className = parent.canvasClasses;
        canvas.width = 100;
        canvas.height = 100;
        parent.previewWrapper.appendChild( canvas );

        var fileCanvas = Canvas.functions.create( canvas );
        parent.canvases.push( fileCanvas );

        reader.onload = function() {
            fileCanvas.sourceImage.src = reader.result;
            parent.functions.render( fileCanvas );
            parent.functions.preview(
                fileCanvas,
                fileCanvas.sourceImage.width / 10,
                fileCanvas.sourceImage.height / 10
            );
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL( file );
    }
};
```

A few notes:

You don't need the outermost IIFE that turns `Canvas.functions` into `this`. Just use `Canvas.functions` directly. That also eliminates any chance of `this` being incorrect inside a callback (doesn't appear that would be a problem here, but it helps keep things simple).

You don't need the `j` variable. `parent.canvases.length` is always the same value as `j`.

If you use `.forEach()` instead of the `for` loop, you get a closure on all the local variables declared inside the `.forEach()` callback. This is really the only closure you need.

OTOH, as you noted, an "array-like" object like `FileReader` may not have a `.forEach()` method. There are a couple of ways ways to address this. One is to write an ordinary `for` loop and call a function in it, e.g.

```
var files = parent.fileInput.files;
for( var i = 0;  i < files.length;  i++ ) {
    doFile( files[i] );
}

function doFile( file ) {
    ...
}
```

This could be done with an inline function expresion, but I like using a separate named function statement for this kind of use - it just seems a little more clear. (The one caveat here would be to not put the function statement itself inside a nested block like an `if` or `for` block - browsers do not handle that consistently - it needs to be directly inside the outer function.

Or, use `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` to let you use `forEach` on the array-like object. I used this approach in the updated code above, by defining a standalone `forEach()` function. You could just put the `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` directly inline, but I think it's cleaner to wrap it in a function. Of course if you're using a library such as Underscore or LoDash there are convenient iterators you can use like `_.each()`.

You don't need to use `document.getElementById()` to get a reference to the current canvas, because you already have it in the `canvas` variable.

You don't need either of the nested closures inside the `onload()` callback. That function already has access to the necessary variables.

The code appears to use the name `canvas` for two very different things. First is the actual `canvas` element that you create at the top, second is the return value from `Canvas.functions.create(canvas)`. I renamed the second one as `fileCanvas` to avoid confusion. You can probably come up with a better name, just don't call it `canvas`.

In the `onload` callback, `r.target` is the same object as `reader`, so you can just use it directly. If you do use a parameter in an event handler like this, I recommend calling it `event` (or `e` if you want a short name) since that is more customary.

Comment: Great. Eliminating the counter `j` in this case solved the scope issue. I had run into issues since the async callback always saw `j` at its max value.  And thanks for catching that canvas != canvas, I +1'ed now because my future self might not remember.

Comment: Couple comments. 1) `forEach()` only works with arrays, not array-like objects (like a `filelist`). 2) `push()` returns a number, not the pushed element.

Comment: Great catch on both issues! Obviously you've fixed these in your own version of the code, but just to keep the example more useful for anyone else who runs across it, I updated the code, hopefully more correct this time. :-)